# Use `async` pipe multiple times on same observable

Tags: angular, observable, ngxs

I am using NGXS to update loading state and state is being updated correctly but i am facing one issue that

**How to use loading state at multiple places in template?**

NGXS selector Looks like as below:

```
@Select(MyAppState.isLoadingLayouts) loading$: Observable<boolean>;
```

Now in my template there is a button which needs to be disabled and loader shall be shown in button while dispatching an action. I tried as below but it did not work. Button is not getting disabled.

```
<button mat-raised-button class="gec-button" (click)="getLayoutsData()" [disabled]="loading">
  <ng-container *ngIf="loading$ | async as loading; else submit">
   <app-progress-bar [diameter]="16"></app-progress-bar>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #submit>Submit</ng-template>
</button>
```

I think we can not use `loading$ | async` multiple times in template as it triggers multiple async calls.

Is there a way we can achieve this single async pipe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. You just need to [`share`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/share) observable between subscribers:

```
public getSharedLoading$() {
  return this.loadging$.pipe(share());
}

*ngIf="getSharedLoading$ | async as loading; else submit"
```

Comment: I think more elegant way is to use share operator

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use async pipe at multiple places, it will trigger request those many times.

To Fix this, try any of the followings :

1) Subscribe it in component and use the property with null check

2) Use [ng-container](https://nitayneeman.com/posts/using-single-subscription-for-multiple-async-pipes-in-angular/)

cheers (y)

Comment: Try wrapping inside ng-container and use alias, worked for me.